# Show current active/logged user who are logged with nginx authentication

Tags: php, linux, authentication, nginx

I'm actually using nginx authentication to provide my users access to my services

It's possible to see the current active/logged users with some information like IP-Username-UserAgent?

Comment: Take a look here to the Nginx core module variables: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24remote_user

Comment: Thanks for your fast request. I can see in access.log file which users are logged in generaly. But I want only see which are current logged in

Comment: You can try to use something like "GoAccess" to parse traffic on your server using command-line: http://goaccess.io